# Porcentaje con php

Tags: php

Estaba investigando en las preguntas, pero no he entendido ninguna respuesta,
Lo que trato de hacer es que me muestre el porcentaje de la siguiente información

```
// Aquí tengo mis Variables
$identificados = 287;
$asignadospa = 9;
$asignadosei = 5;
$cerrados = 0;

//Aquí los sumo

$totalPips = $asignadospa + $asignadosei + $cerrados;
// totalPips = 14

//Divido
$totalDec = $totalPips / $identificados;
// El total es: 0.048780487804878
```

Lo que quiero realizar es que el $totalDec se convierta en porcentaje.

Comment: Multiplicarlo por 100??

Answer (score 2):

No entiendo muy bien tu pregunta David.

Pero para sacar temas de porcentajes deberias intentar redondear ese resultado utilizando round() para evitar que se genere ese numero tan grande que muestras

Aca te dejo un codigo de ejemplo.

```
$porcentajeTotal  = round($totalDec * 100);
$echo $porcentajeTotal . "%";
```

Comment: Es correcto, esto es lo que buscaba!